# Какими членами предложения являются слова в данном предложении?

Tags: синтаксис, сказуемые, определения, члены-предложения, подлежащее

Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться:

Тот, что в шляпе - Константин, наш учитель.

Вижу так: **тот, что в шляпе** - подлежащее, **Константин** - определение, **наш** - определение, **учитель** - сказуемое.

Comment: По-моему, у Вас пропущена запятая после придаточного "что в шляпе". Правильной была бы такая пунктуация: _Тот, что в шляпе, — Константин, наш учитель._ Попробуйте при такой пунктуации найти основу предложения.

Comment: Спасибо за подсказку! Там контекст несколько другой

Comment: Хочу поддержать мнение Славы (Тот, что в шляпе, — Константин, наш учитель). Надо поставить закрывающую запятую. А так у Вас по смыслу получается  в "шляпе-Константин". Есть еще вариант пунктуации: _Тот, что в шляпе, Константин  — наш учитель._ Дайте же контекст — помозгуем.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Возможный вариант: ***Тот**, что в шляпе, Константин, — наш **учитель**.*

***Тот*** — подлежащее, выраженное указательным местоимением в значении существительного. ***Учитель*** — именная часть сказуемого.

К подлежащему относится  местоименно-определительное придаточное предложение **что в шляпе** и уточняющее приложение ***Константин***. ***Наш*** — определение.